# TTF and Relibility data form

Tags: reliability

Assume the car engine has 4 failure in one month. 
Example: Failure at day 10, 15, 23, 29. 
Is TTF  maintained after each failure as shown in the following table, or it is increasing?
How to calculate reliability at each point by Benard approximation.

```
R(Ti) = 1 − i − 0.3/n + 0.4
```

Where `i` is failure order and `n` sample size

```
Failure     TTF    R(Ti)
Day 10       10 
Day 15       5
Day 23       8
Day 29       6
```

Comment: When you test a bunch of objects until failure, one of them is the first to go, another is the second, and so on.  That's what's being tabulated.

Comment: @whuber  So, TTF should not be increased. TTF is maintained after each failure. Maybe longer or shorter.

Comment: I don't follow that.  When you order the objects by time to failure, by the *very construction* of the table the time to failure (TTF) increases!

Comment: @whuber, Let me say this. My car engine failed many times this month. first failure at day 10, second failure at day 15, last failure at day 18. So TTF is 10, 5, and 3 respectively. because TTF between second failure and last failure is shorter than TTF between first and second.

Comment: I think you will need to explain more about what that table shows, because I see no relationship between it and the car engine failures you are quoting.  In particular, it isn't clear whether it tabulates 40 separate objects or repeated tests on a single object (or even something else).  What is a "suit" of turbochargers??

Comment: @whuber, I edit the post